# What is wrong with my loops for the game Master Mind? (javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, loops

I am trying to make a javascript/html game of Master Mind. 
(Rules are located here)
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mastermind_%28board_game%29

Basically you have 4 colors hidden from the user. The user tries to guess the colors. The program will only return the following info.

1)The number of correct colors in the correct place.

2)The number of correct colors in the incorrect place.

3)The number of incorrect colors.

I want the code to create a red circle for each correct answer, white for each correct color, but incorrect place, and grey for wrong answer.
I feel like my logic is correct but the program keeps spitting out incorrect data. I feel like I am missing something. 
Any help would be awesome.

```
var guessedAlready = [4];
var correctAlready = [4];
for(var i = 0; i<4; i++)                                   //set array to see if answer was already guessed
    {
correctAlready[i] = 0;
guessedAlready[i] = 0;  
     }  
for(var i = 0; i<4; i++)
{
if(color1 == answerArray [i])
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        correctAnswer += 1; 

    guessedAlready[i] = 1;
    }
    if (guessedAlready[i] != 1)
    {
        incorrectPlace +=1;
    }

    guessedAlready[i] = 1;
}

if(color2 == answerArray [i])
{
    if(i == 1)
    {
        correctAnswer+=1;

        if(guessedAlready[i] == 1)
        {
        incorrectPlace -= 1;
        }
    }

    if (guessedAlready[i] != 1)
    {
        incorrectPlace +=1;
    }
    guessedAlready[i]=1;
}
if(color3 == answerArray [i])
{
    if(i == 2)
    {
        correctAnswer+=1;

        if(guessedAlready[i] == 1)
        {
        incorrectPlace -= 1;
        }
    }

    if (guessedAlready[i] != 1)
    {
        incorrectPlace +=1;
    }
    guessedAlready[i]=1;
}
if(color4 == answerArray [i])
{
    if(i == 3)
    {
        correctAnswer += 1; 
        if(guessedAlready[i] == 1)
            {
            incorrectPlace -=1;
            }
    }

    if (guessedAlready[i] != 1)
    {       
        incorrectPlace +=1;
    }
    guessedAlready[i]=1;
}
 }


 wrongAnswer = 4-incorrectPlace-correctAnswer;
 //---------------------------------------------------------------creates divs for each correct, incorrectly placed, and wrong answer---------------//
 for(var i = 0; i<correctAnswer; i++)
 {
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.className = 'pastAnswerShow';
myElement.id = 'answerShow'+tracker;
pastAnswerBox.appendChild(myElement);
myElement.style.background = 'black';
keyTracker+=1;
 }

 for(var i = 0; i <incorrectPlace; i++)
 {
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.className = 'pastAnswerShow';
myElement.id = 'answerShow'+tracker;
pastAnswerBox.appendChild(myElement);
myElement.style.background = 'white';
keyTracker+=1;
 }

 for(var i = 0; i<wrongAnswer; i++)
 {  
var myElement = document.createElement('div');
myElement.className = 'pastAnswerShow';
myElement.id = 'answerShow'+tracker;
pastAnswerBox.appendChild(myElement);
myElement.style.background = 'grey';
keyTracker+=1;
 }
```

Comment: Could you perhaps build a jsFiddle?

Comment: What exactly is the problem? the error Message? what is not happening? It Might be better to splitt the code in smaller parts, and only post the relevant pices, if you know them.

Comment: Why do you have `correctAlready` defined and never use it?

Answer (score 0):

You have it in your first one, but you need to add

```
guessedAlready[i]=1;
```

in if i = 1, i = 2 and i = 3 like this:

```
if(i == 3)
{
    correctAnswer += 1; 
    if(guessedAlready[i] == 1)
    {
        incorrectPlace -=1;
    }
    guessedAlready[i]=1;
}
```

That should fix your logic issue